# Какие коды http являются success?

Tags: веб-программирование, api, http

Подскажите пожалуйста, с какого и по какой коды являются **success**?

Просто пишу класс `JsonResponse`, хочу чтобы он определял по коду, ошибка эта или все таки **success**.

Знаю, что только код `200` **OK**

Comment: 200+ Ок. [Коды html ответов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

Comment: Смысле 200+ это ок? 404 это уже не success

Comment: аа, увидел, 200-299

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста, код на пустое поле, это 404?

Comment: 404 - не найдено. И это коды HTTP ответов, а не результат парсинга страницы

Comment: Ну ведь я должен же вернуть какое-то код

Comment: Я бы выбрал 400 - плохой запрос. Или 409 - конфликт состояния

Comment: Ну редиректы-то тоже можно считать успехом, наверное? (Впрочем, редиректы и JsonResponse не очень сочетаются)

Comment: @andreymal редирект надо перейти и уже там получить сукес

Comment: а пустое поле - это не заполненное поле или поле с пустотой? в первом случае 404, во втором 204

Comment: @SwaD эти ответы говорят о плохом запросе, а не о наличии ответа

Comment: @eri а это как посмотреть. Если в запросе нет данных для поля, то запрос можно посчитать кривым )

Comment: @eri, так поле пустое и поле не заполнено, это одно и тоже :)

Comment: @eri, 204 - это успешный ответ, такого быть же не может :)

Comment: пустой горшок и отсутствие горшка - это не одно и тоже. пускай без меда, но 204 это успешно выполненный запрос.

Comment: Абсолютно не логично, что вы написали, вообще никак не совпадает с тем, что я написал высше.

Comment: Жду от вас пример кода, где будет проверка на пустоту и на то, что поле не заполнено

Answer (score 1):

##### 2xx (200-299) - Успешно(Success)

Самый расспространенный код **200** - **ОК**(Все успешно)

##### 1xx (100-199) - Информационные(Informational)

Например **101**, при переключении протокола с `http` на `ws`

##### 3xx (300-399) - Перенаправление(Redirection)

Например **301** - перенаправление на другую страниц

##### 4xx (400-499) - Ошибка клиента(Client error)

Известный **404** - Не найдено или **401** - Не авторизованы

##### 5xx (500-599) - Ошибка сервера(Server error)

Допустим **503** - сервис не доступен